# Using Google Analytics to Track Stats Only for Visitors (Not Visits) Who Converted

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, visitors

I'm having trouble setting up the right Google Analytics reporting for my website.

- I want to know the "Total Visits", "Pages / Visit", and "Avg. Time on Site" (I'll call these "stats" from now on) for all visitors who converted.
- A conversion occurs only when a visitor accesses a specific page on the site, "download.php". I have added a custom event to this page and used that to define a Conversion Goal in Google Analytics.
- What I need to know is the stats for all the visitors who converted, with these stats factoring in all their visits' data, not just the visit during which they converted.
- The problem is, since the link to "download.php" is sent by email after a verification process, it can come days later and it is treated as a completely separate visit.
- Furthermore, I also want to *not* count the visit to "download.php" towards the stats, so that page could only be used to track the custom event, thereby tracking conversions.

So far I've tried to use Advanced Segments, but couldn't find a way to track visitors instead of visits with conversions, which seemed to be the only option there. I appreciate any help!